# Python typying module for typesafety

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, type-safety, python-typing

`python 3.7`

I came from Scala with strict type system and this example got me confused:

```
from typing import Optional

tst: Optional[int] = None
tst2: int = None
tst3: Optional[int] = 'string'

print(tst)  # prints None
print(tst2) # prints None
print(tst3) # prints string
```

It executes fine without any error.

So the type annotations are only for description and external tools (like linters) and does not affect python runtime itself? Or I missed something

Comment: That's correct. They're simply hints to static analysis tools.

Comment: If you want to enforce these type hints, you could use come external library such as mypy: https://github.com/python/mypy

Comment: "Static", not "strict". Python has a *strong* type system, in which every *object* has  a type and no implicit conversion are done to those objects, but it is also a *dynamic* type system, which means a name can refer to an object without regard to the object's type. Type hints are a way of indicating your *intent* for a name to only refer to objects of a particular type. Third-party tools like `mypy` can check that you are not violating the stated intent, but type hints have no effect on *running* code.

Comment: Python *can* make use of the type hints at run time, but not in a way that breaks dynamic typing. For example, the `dataclass` decorator uses the presence of a type hint, if not necessarily the exact hint, to indicate what instance attributes should be available for a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: yes, these annotations are mainly just for external tools. The type annotations do not materially change the way the program executes, and you correctly note that a Python program with type errors can execute just fine.

Just to elaborate a little bit, these type hints come from [PEP-483](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0483/) and [PEP-484](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/). These proposals make a distinction between a "type" (the thing you annotate) and "class" (which is actually meaningful at runtime):

> Every class is a type as discussed above. But it is tricky and error prone to implement a class that exactly represents semantics of a given type, and it is not a goal of PEP 484. The static types described in PEP 484, should not be confused with the runtime classes.